# Using a function pointer as parameter

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list

I am trying to add a node to the front of a linked list using the following:

```
struct Node *addFront(struct List *list, void *data) {
```

So far I have the following:

```
struct Node *front = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)){
    if(front == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    front->data = data;

    if(list->head == 0) {
        list->head = front;
        front->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        list->head = front;
        *front->next =*
    }

    return front;
}
```

I am confused as to what an added node would point to if it is not the first node to be created... I would like to say something like:
    front->next = list;
But list is of type List so I'm sure I'd get some incompatible assignment error..what is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Node *oldHead = list->head;
list->head = front;
front->next =oldHead;
```

Store the old head, and assign it to `front->next`.

Or just

```
front->next =list->head;
list->head = front;
```

Will suffice.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a newbie at this (as you can see). Help greatly appreciated.